# Wait doesn't allow the JFrame to update

Tags: java, swing, jframe, wait, notify

In my program, I need to wait for the user to input from a JFrame. When the user is done with the first input they press a JButton. This calls a constructor for a Class I made: HumanTrainer. In the constructor I need the user to have more inputs. I made two functions to wait and notify. But when the code gets to wait, everything freezes, and the JFrame doesn't update to what it should.

This is the action the first button preforms

```
startingButton.addActionListener((e)->{
        Trainer[]t=new Trainer[2];//HumanTrainer extends Trainer
        String[]names=new String[2];
        for(int a=0;a<2;a++)
            names[a]=((JTextField)(startingInputs[2][1+a])).getText();
        grid.removeAll();//The JPanel that the Frame has
        Frame.repaint();//The JFrame
        Frame.validate();
        if(isHuman[0])
            t[0]=new HumanTrainer(names[0],grid,Frame);//The constructor
        if(isHuman[1])
            t[1]=new HumanTrainer(names[1],grid,Frame);

    });
```

And the constructor for HumanTrainer

```
HumanTrainer(String name,JPanel grid,JFrame Frame){
    super(name);

    GridBagConstraints manager=new GridBagConstraints();
    manager.gridx=0;
    manager.gridy=0;
    manager.gridheight=1;
    manager.gridwidth=1;
    manager.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    Font Format=new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN,14);

    JButton cont=new JButton("Continue");//This is the button that when clicked should run the function that notifies

    grid.add(cont,manager);

    grid.repaint();//One of these four things SHOULD change the view of the frame
    grid.validate();
    Frame.repaint();
    Frame.validate();

    System.out.print("TEST");//This prints
    cont.addActionListener((e)->{
        made();//This is a function contained in HumanTrainer that only calls notify();
    });
    make();//This is a function contained in HumanTrainer that only calls wait(); With the proper try and catch
}
```

But when starterButton is pressed the screen freezes and doesn't update so that cont can be pressed.

Comment: If you want to wait for user input, use a modal `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`

Comment: @MadProgrammer But I need the inputs from the HumanTrainer constructor before the code continues past the creation of both Trainers. Using a JDialog doesn't pause the code execution.

Comment: *"Using a JDialog doesn't pause the code execution"* - Ah, yeah, they do, unless you're executing your code outside of the EDT (or not using a modal dialog), which means you have other issues to deal with

Comment: Based on your description of your out-of-context code, calling `wait` within the context of the EDT will block the EDT and freeze your program

Comment: Well could you tell me how, maybe what I know about JDialogs isn't complete. I thought that they only restrict interaction with the origonal frame, if you so choose. I didn't think that you can also pause code. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @JamesLeavens: that's what *modal* dialogs do -- they pause program flow from when the are set visible until they are no longer visible, just like a JOptionPane (which *is* a modal JDialog).

Comment: AFAIR, they will, by default, block the entire EDT (all the current windows), but you can configure it to only block (focus) to particular windows, but a modal dialog takes over the event dispatching, so it should block the code exactly where you call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).  Swing uses a single thread to dispatch it's events from, if you perform any long running or blocking operation from within the EDT (like calling `wait`), then it freeze your program and the user will have to terminate it.

You have two basic choices.  You can either use a modal dialog to gather information from the user, see [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), which will block the execution of the code at the point they are displayed, without blocking the entire EDT OR use a observer pattern, which can generate notifications that the user has provided what ever information you are expecting.

To be honest, a modal dialog is generally easier and can help prevent unexpected side effects

This...

`make();//This is a function contained in HumanTrainer that only calls wait(); With the proper try and catch`

would seem to be the core of your problem, but without more information and context of what you are trying to do, it's impossible to really suggest what you should do, however I'd recommend having a look at [model-view-controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) and seperare your code into more appropriate layers

Comment: Yeah the make function was a stretch. I kept it in because it was the last thing I had tried before putting it on StackOverflow. I'll try the modal Dialog and get back to you about it :)

Comment: If you're still having issues, consider providing a runnable example of what you're doing and more details about what you're trying to, base on your description of your problem, this seems to be the way to solve it

Comment: Using a Modal Dialog did stop the code, and it allows me to do what I needed. I didn't know about that. Thanks! Also sorry, I'm really bad at explaining what I need done/what my code does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may want to close that for loop with `{}` so that it doesn't loop the whole code twice. Also you should check if `wait()` and `notify()` work correctly by individually testing them without java awt.

Comment: The for loop doesn't have a { so it only loops the next line of code

Comment: How would I check to see if wait() and notify() work correctly, could you provide a sample.

Comment: You should have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see why that's a bad idea

Comment: @JamesLeavens You can easily test wait and notify by doing a dry run.